# How to get a callback or notification on a call or cancel action in default iOS "call" popup?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get a callback or notification if a user clicked on a "call" or "cancel" button when trying to call a phone number from the app. I use the following code:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "tel://\(number)") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { didCall in
  print(didCall)
}
```

Issue with this callback is that it is triggered when the dialog appears not when I click any of the buttons and it is always true. I couldn't find another solution. I know that since iOS 10 there's a notification I can subscribe to to get information if user clicked "Allow" or "Don't allow" notifications but similar thing doesn't seem to exist for call action.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/) state that the prompt will always appear when calling `tel` but since the prompt is made outside of your app, you can't do anything to observe it.